# Stata の dta ファイルを開くには？

Tags: r, rstudio

現在イギリス大学院課程をオンラインにて履修中の者です。

統計学の授業内で R と RStudio、および指定のdtaファイルをダウンロードするように指示されました。

RStudioのダウンロードまでは問題なく進んだのですが、dtaファイルをダウンロードすると、添付の画像のように文字化けして表記されます。よく見るとところどころ英語が確認できるのですが…

こちらはなぜ文字化けしているのか、またどうしたら正常にダウンロードできるのか、RStudioに詳しい方に教えていただきたいです。ちなみにパソコンはMacです。よろしくお願いします。

[image: 文字化け]

Comment: `.dta` という拡張子なので、おそらく Stata のデータファイルで、バイナリ形式なのだと思います。つまり、直接内容を表示して確認するのではなく、R の関数を使って読み込むものかと思います。

Comment: 履修しているなら講師なり問い合わせ窓口なりあるでしょうからそちらに訊ねてみれば良いのでは？

Comment: >kunifさん　仰る通り問い合わせたのですが、担当者が休暇中なので休暇明けまで待つように言われ、早期に解決したかったのでこちらで質問させていただきました。

>metropolisさん　ありがとうございます。Stataのデータファイルということは、Stataをインストールしたら正常に読み込めるということでしょうか？
Rの関数を使って読み込むとは、具体的にどのような手順でインストールしたらよいのでしょうか？すみません、完全に初歩的な質問で申し訳ないです。

Comment: @プログラミング超初心者 幾つか方法はありますが、授業で使っているテキストにその辺りの事は書かれていませんか？ 例えば、このサイトから R のパッケージをダウンロードして云々とか、`install.packages` を使って云々などです。

Comment: metropolisさんのキーワードで検索するとこんなのが関連してそうですが。[他の統計ソフト用のデータを読む Stata](https://yukiyanai.github.io/jp/classes/econometrics2/contents/R/data-handling.html#section-2), [Read and write Stata DTA files](https://haven.tidyverse.org/reference/read_dta.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

コメント欄でも指摘がありますが、Stata 形式という **バイナリファイル** であり、テキストファイルのように中身が直接表示できるわけではありません。

Rstudio もインストールしているなら、ファイルメニューからインポートすることができるようです。

[Stataのデータ (.dta) ファイルをRで開くときの3つのやり方](https://scientia-socialis-f-discolor.hatenablog.com/entry/2020/03/31/212020)

> RStudioで [File]->[Import Dataset]->[From Stata]

Comment: ＞metropolisさん、kunifさん　cubick♦︎さん　cubick♦︎さんより共有いただいたリンクを元に作業したところ、無事にRstudioにdtaファイルをインストールできましたことを報告いたします。今回バイナリファイルというものの存在について初めて知り、大変勉強になりました。私に基礎知識がないにも関わらずみなさま親身にアドバイスをくださり、本当にありがとうございました。心より感謝申し上げます。

Comment: 回答から時間が経っていますが, 質問者にほとんど知識がないことが伺えますので補足します: RStudio のインポート機能は haven パッケージによるもので, Rでのdtaファイルのインポートはこれでうまくいくことが多いと思いますが, haven 自体は Stata が公式にサポートしているものではありません. Stata のような有償ソフトウェアを使うことが前提の授業なら, ソフトの使用に関するサポートが一切ないのは不自然だと思いますので, (もうすでになさってるかもしれませんが) 授業の責任者に問い合わせることをお勧めします.